# How to configure hockey app in portable for uwp?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, hockeyapp

I have a UWP windows 10 application and I have used MVVM in the project. All the ViewModels are present in the portable project.

How do I configure the hockey app in portable for UWP windows 10 application? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: all you need is https://hockeyapp.net/blog/2016/02/15/hockeysdk-for-uwp-apps.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I configure the hockey app in portable for UWP windows 10 application?

Add to Jet Chopper's suggestion, the HocyeyApp is supported in UWP. This document [HockeyApp for Applications on Windows](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/hockeyapp-for-applications-on-windows#setup) has detailed steps about how to setup and use it.

The main code as about configuration as the following:

```
HockeyClient.Current.Configure("App id on dashboard");
```

Comment: Thanks. Somehow the hockeyapp core dll was missing in the portable project. After fixing the issue it working fine.